# There has been a critical error on this website. WordPress & google cloud platform (GCP)

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform

Hi brothers and sisters . I got this problem "There has been a critical error on this website.

Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress."  on my [cpuflat.com](https://cpuflat.com) website , its been two weeks facing this problem , and i try alot of thinks to fix it but non of that things work .even I can't access my wp-admin .
I start bndiagnostic tool on SSh and got this results :
I
===== Begin of bndiagnostic tool output =====

Action '-t -f /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

```
? Connectivity: Found possible issues
? Resources: Found possible issues
✓ Php: No issues found
? Wordpress: Found possible issues
✓ Mariadb: No issues found
✓ Processes: No issues found
? Apache: Found possible issues
```

[Connectivity]

Server ports 22, 80 and/or 443 are not publicly accessible. Please check the
following guide to open server ports for remote access:

https://docs.bitnami.com/general/faq/administration/use-firewall/

Press [Enter] to continue:
[Resources]

Your instance has little available RAM memory.

```
 total used free shared buff/cache available Mem: 575 370 40 14 164 90 Swap: 634 
169 465
```

You could try to increase your instance's memory. Please check your cloud
provider's documentation for more information.

[Wordpress]

Some files don't have the expected permissions Please check the following guide:

https://docs.bitnami.com/general/apps/wordpress/administration/understand-
file-permissions/

Found recent WordPress plugin related error messages in the Apache error log.

```
[Mon Sep 11 17:25:03.401646 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 25389:tid 
139903576823552] [client **ip_address**:34832] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: 
PHP Fatal error: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no 
longer supported in /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/mu-plugins/index.php on line 
Press [Enter] to continue:
2'
```

Please check the following guide to deactivate plugins:

https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/plugin/deactivate/

[Apache]

Found recent error or warning messages in the Apache error log.

```
[Mon Sep 11 16:19:31.392058 2023] [authz_core:error] [pid 25123:tid 
139902662444800] [client **ip_address**:40800] AH01630: client denied by server 
configuration: /opt/bitnami/apache/cgi-bin
```

Please check the following guide to troubleshoot server issues:

https://docs.bitnami.com/general/apps/wordpress/troubleshooting/debug-erro
rs-apache/

The Apache configuration has errors:

```
Press [Enter] to continue:
apache2: Syntax error on line 112 of /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: 
module log_config_module is built-in and can't be loaded
```

Comment: Do you know if your hosting provider provides backup restore? If so, you could restore your site to a date right before these issues occurred.